# Cannot configure TOTP in Keycloak 1.7.0 Final

Tags: authentication, wildfly, totp

I am using a Keycloak 1.7.0 Final and I am trying to configure TOTP for a user.
Once I set the required action (Configure TOTP), at the first login I get the configuration page with the QR and the confirmation code. If I setup the TOTP, the required action disappears (as it was completed), the TOTP flag is set to 1 but at the next login the OTP code request is skipped. If I set "REQUIRED" in the authentication flow for OTP Form, the configuration is requested at every login as it was never been configured.

What am I leaving behind?

P.S. With keycloak 18.X in another system I have, it works perfectly.